# (Node js) - TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, typeerror

I've been looking around for a few days not and really I feel like I'm missing a part of the concept here... I'm fairly new with node.js, and I'm trying to call a method from a different module in my main class per-say...

Here is the code..

inputReader.js

```
    (function() {
    var dir = './views/';   // Declare the directory to be scanned
    var data = {}   // Create array object for storage 

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var c = 0;  // Declare a var c = 0; initial condition of a for loop
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            c++;    // Increment a counter in the for-loop condition
            fs.readFile(dir+file, 'utf-8', function(err, string) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if ( 0 === -3) {
                    data[file] = string;    // Throws into data object string of contents within the file being read
                    console.log(data);  // We only need this to test using console (the contents being stored)
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
    module.exports.getData = function() {
        return data();
    }
}());
```

And here is how I'm trying to call it in app.js

```
    var inputReader = require('./inputReader').inputReader;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(inputReader.getData());
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

My prediction for if I did this correctly, my localhost page would display the contents of the files within the folder I designated the app to read; ./views/.. but clearly, I am doing something very wrong as the error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined at c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\app.js:21:24 at callbacks (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5) at Object.router (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10) at next (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at Object.expressInit [as handle] (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5) at next (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at Object.query [as handle] (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:44:5)

If someone may point me to the right direction or explain to me what I am doing wrong, that would be appreciated

Thank you! (And sorry for the long read..)

Comment: Try var inputReader = require('./inputReader') (without the additional .inputReader).

Comment: It wouldn't explain your error, but I don't understand the `return data();` line. `data` is an object, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Several different way to write it out:

```
// inputReader.js
module.exports.getData = function() {
    return data();
}

// app.js
var inputReader = require('./inputReader'); // inputReader contains getData
inputReader.getData();
```

or

```
// inputReader.js
module.exports.getData = function() {
    return data();
}

// app.js
var inputReader = require('./inputReader').getData; // inputReader is now getData
inputReader();
```

or

```
// inputReader.js
var theModule = {
    getData : function() {
        return data();
    }
}

module.exports = theModule;

// app.js
var inputReader = require('./inputReader');
inputReader.getData();
```

or

```
// inputReader.js
var theModule = function() { /* constructor */ };

theModule.prototype.getData = function() {
    return data();
};

module.exports = theModule;

// app.js
var inputReader = require('./inputReader');
new inputReader().getData();
```