# Node.js: Making internal calls from exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Suppose I have the following code in one of my modules:

```
var _this = this;
exports.getData = function(res) {
  res.json({someData:'Data'});
};
```

Now I want to make another `exports` function within my module that makes use of `getData`.
Basically somehow make something of this sort:

```
exports.getMoreData = function(res) {
  $.nodeInternalCall({url: _this.getData()}).done(function(data) {
    res.json({newData: data.someData * 10})
  })
};
```

Is there any way to do this? Unless this doesn't make sense in node D:

Comment: the answer to this question will be similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19690642/1481489 look over all the variations in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this; the simplest is simply to reference it literally as `exports.getData`:

```
exports.otherFunction = function(res) {
    return exports.getData(res);
};
```

You can also assign the function to a variable for easy reference in other functions.

```
var getData = exports.getData = function(res) {};

exports.otherFunction = function(res) {
    return getData(res);
};
```

The advantage of the first approach is that it doesn't matter what order the functions are defined in (as long as you don't invoke a function that depends on another function before defining the other).

The advantage of the second is that it's shorter to type, and if you later change your mind and decide not to expose the function as part of the module you can remove the `exports.getData =` without needing to refactor all the rest of the code.